# rbind data based on matching values in a column

Tags: r, rbind

I have several data frames I would like to combine, but I need to get rid of rows that don't have matching values in a column in the other data frames. For example, I want to merge a, b, and c data frames, based on the values in column x.

```
a <- data.frame(1:5, 5:9)
colnames(a) <- c("x", "y")
b <- data.frame(1:4, 7:10)
colnames(b) <- c("x", "y")
c <- data.frame(1:3, 6:8)
colnames(c) <- c("x", "y")
```

and have the result be

```
1   5
2   6
3   7
1   7
2   8
3   9
1   6
2   7
3   8
```

where the first three rows are from data frame a, the second three rows are from data frame b, and the third three rows are from data frame c, and the rows that didn't have matching values in column x were not included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create an index based on `intersect`ing elements of 'x'

```
v1 <- Reduce(intersect, list(a$x, b$x, c$x))
rbind(a[a$x %in% v1,], b[b$x %in% v1,], c[c$x %in% v1, ])
#  x y
#1 1 5
#2 2 6
#3 3 7
#4 1 7
#5 2 8
#6 3 9
#7 1 6
#8 2 7
#9 3 8
```

If there are many dataset objects, it is better to keep it in a `list`.  Here, the example showed the object identifiers as completely different, but if the identifiers have a pattern e.g. `df1, df2, ..df100` etc, it becomes easier to get it to a `list`

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$"))
```

If the object identifiers are all different `xyz, abc, fq12` etc, but these are the only data.frame objects loaded in the global environment

```
lst1 <-  mget(names(eapply(.GlobalEnv, 'is.data.frame')))
```

Then, get the interesecitng elements of the column 'x'

```
v1 <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(lst1, `[[`, "x"))
```

Use the intersecting vector to subset the rows of the `list` elements

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, function(x) dat[dat$x %in% v1,]))
```

Here, we assume the column names are the same across all the datasets

---

Another option is to do a `merge` and then `unlist`

```
out <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'x'), list(a, b, c))
data.frame(x = out$x, y = unlist(out[-1], use.name = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks! can you explain a bit how the second option works? I don't want to list all the data frames individually because there are many of them. My code is ```out <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'word'), list(list_by_file[grepl("_1", names(list_by_file))]))

data.frame(x = out$word, y = unlist(out[-1], use.name = FALSE))``` but I get the error ```Error in data.frame(x = out$word, y = unlist(out[-1], use.name = FALSE)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 12903```

Comment: @Lisa If the data.frame identifiers are different as you showed, you may need `mget(ls())` assuming you have only those data.frames created in the global env

Comment: @Lisa Regarding the error, it could be result of unequal lengths.  You can replicate the 'our$x` column to match the length of the `unlist`ed output

Comment: the ```out``` object seems to just be reproducing the list I give it. My actual data has more than two columns. Could this be the problem? I am new to R and am unfamiliar with ```...```, so I'm not entirely sure what is happening there.

Comment: @Lisa Yes, that is the problem.  Here, I have assumed that there are only two columns.  You can subset the dataset within the `list` and then do the `merge`

Comment: @Lisa e.g.`lapply(lst1, funcftion(x) x[colsofInterest])` and use that in the `merge`

Comment: I actually need all of the columns in the data. would that be possible? apologies if I am misunderstanding

Comment: @Lisa Sure, In that, case, the first approach would be better.  I would place all the dataset in to a list first `lst1 <- mget(ls()); v1 <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(lst1, "[", "x"));  do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, function(dat) dat[dat$x %in% v1,]))`

Comment: @Lisa I updated the post with some more info. Hope it helps